# How can I get a list of errors from phpmailer?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm sending emails through PHPMailer and I found a specific case when the email address is a non-existing email address that belongs to the sending gateway 
`[ e.g - gateway email: 1234@1234.com and the email address 0000@1234.com]`, phpmailer returns the following error: "Recipient address rejected user unknown in virtual mailbox table".

It would be great if a status code might be present there (I want to know if is a hard bounce or a soft bounce) and also, I want to know what kind of other specific cases might occur.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP errors are covered by [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.2) and related RFCs, and you can see most significant errors codes there. When you get an SMTP error in PHPMailer, the SMTP error code is put in the `$error` property of the SMTP instance, which is protected, but you can fetch it using `getError()`. From normal PHP code this would be done with:

```
$error = $mail->getSMTPInstance()->getError();
```

The result is an array like this:

```
[
    'error' => $message,
    'detail' => $detail,
    'smtp_code' => $smtp_code,
    'smtp_code_ex' => $smtp_code_ex,
]
```

The thing that will be of most interest to you is the `smtp_code` element.

Note that this only applies when you're sending via SMTP; if you're sending via `mail()`, this won't be populated.

Comment: I'm sending via SMTP, but unfortunately there are no details there. If I set the debug option: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, I can see the logs but SMTPDebug must not be enabled on production so it doesn't help me. Anyway, thank you!